# Retrigger router guards when auth state changes

Tags: angular, router

Our application has lots of pages that are public, some that are private.

When a user is logged out for any reason, we would like to maintain their context if they are on a public page, but redirect to the root page if they are on a private page.

Because it is not always easy to determine if the current page is private or not, we really just want to retrigger the angular route guards on the current route. If it's a private page, the guard will redirect appropriately.

We tried using `this.navigateByUrl(this.router.url)` for this purpose, but Angular does nothing if the router detects that the navigation target is already the current page.

Is there a way to trigger route guards to run on the current route, specifically for cases where the state has changed in a way that could likely affect these guards?

Comment: May be with a service with a Subject for exemple where you check if user is logged and then subscribe to it in every components where logged user is required.

Comment: It seemed like setting `onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'` would do the trick (https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#onSameUrlNavigation), but didn't appear to make any difference. Current solution is to just redirect back to `'/'` as we know this is a public page, but having to lose the user's context is unfortunate...